# Already purchased software missing in the software centre

Tags: software-center, paid-applications

I wanted to install some stuff that should be available for Ubuntu 13.04, but when I click on an item I can either find manually or search through USC, it sometimes tells me it is not available in the current software sources.

It however happens only for (but all) already purchased apps, but not for the stuff I haven't purchased yet. The error message is always the same:

```
There isn’t a software package called “cave-story-plus” in your current software sources.
```

[image: visual example]

Also, reinstall previous purchases gives me a blank page.

Is it a bug or is there something I did wrong? I wasn't able to find an answer to it, all that google found was something about missing dependencies, which is apparently not this case.
I should probably submit a bug report to Launchpad, will do it later today if I find out it is not my fault.

Thank you very much :)

Comment: I just filled a bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/1200714